# Why use std::forward in concepts?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

I was reading the [cppreference page on Constraints](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) and noticed this example:

```
// example constraint from the standard library (ranges TS)
template <class T, class U = T>
concept bool Swappable = requires(T t, U u) {
    swap(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u));
    swap(std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<T>(t));
};
```

I'm puzzled why they're using `std::forward`.  Some attempt to support reference types in the template parameters?  Don't we want to call `swap` with lvalues, and wouldn't the `forward` expressions be rvalues when `T` and `U` are scalar (non-reference) types?

For example, I would expect this program to fail given their `Swappable` implementation:

```
#include <utility>

// example constraint from the standard library (ranges TS)
template <class T, class U = T>
concept bool Swappable = requires(T t, U u) {
    swap(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u));
    swap(std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<T>(t));
};

class MyType {};
void swap(MyType&, MyType&) {}

void f(Swappable& x) {}

int main()
{
    MyType x;
    f(x);
}
```

Unfortunately g++ 7.1.0 gives me an [internal compiler error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f17cf55137efefa), which doesn't shed much light on this.

Here both `T` and `U` should be `MyType`, and `std::forward<T>(t)` should return `MyType&&`, which can't be passed to my `swap` function.

Is this implementation of `Swappable` wrong?  Have I missed something?

Comment: Is Concepts really to be part of c++1z?

Comment: No, it's not. I was being too optimistic :)

Comment: As an aside, the internal error seems to be caused by using `Swappable` as a template constraint.  If used as a requirement, GCC seems to be able to handle it properly.  Or more specifically, `void f(Swappable& x) {}` and `template<Swappable S> void f(S& x) {}` both cause an internal error, but `template<typename S> void f(S& x) requires Swappable<S> {}` compiles (and emits an error, because `std::forward` does indeed make it look for an rvalue reference version).

Comment: [It seems to have that problem with any concept that takes two template parameters, with the second defaulting to the first (i.e., any concept with `template<typename T, typename U = T>`).](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f807607d0695023)  When it encounters the concept in actual use, it doesn't seem to be able to properly deduce the parameters while expanding the concept, necessitating the use of `requires` syntax (so that one parameter is already deduced before the concept is encountered, allowing it to deduce the other from that).

Comment: That was a typo in n4382, fixed to use forwarding reference

Comment: @Cubbi What do you mean? Can you expand on that? Maybe an answer?

Comment: Further testing suggests that the internal error is specifically caused by an interaction between `Swappable`'s implied wildcard argument and `U`'s default template argument, as specified in my answer below.  Long story short, while the wildcard perfectly matches `T`, GCC can't temporarily instantiate `U` as the same wildcard; instead, it tries to determine `U`, which requires it to deduce `T`, which requires it to resolve `Swappable`, which requires it to determine `U`, which requires it to deduce `T`, and so on.

Comment: @aschepler I mean that's how it appears in n4382. Commented on JustinTime's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Don't we want to call swap with lvalues […]

That’s a very good question. A question of API design specifically: what meaning or meanings should the designer of a concept library give to the parameters of its concepts?

A quick recap on Swappable requirements. That is, the actual requirements that already appear in today’s Standard and have been here since before concepts-lite:

> - An object `t` is *swappable with* an object `u` if and only if:
>
>   - […] the expressions `swap(t, u)` and `swap(u, t)` are valid […]
>
> […]
>
> An rvalue or lvalue `t` is swappable if and only if t is swappable with any rvalue or lvalue, respectively, of type `T`.

(Excerpts butchered from [`Swappable` requirements [swappable.requirements]](http://eel.is/c++draft/swappable.requirements) to cut down on a whole lot of irrelevant details.)

## Variables

Did you catch that? The first bit gives requirements that match your expectations. It’s quite straightforward to turn into an actual concept†, too:

<sup>†: as long as we’re willing to ignore a ton of details that are outside our scope</sup>

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs = Lhs>
concept bool FirstKindOfSwappable = requires(Lhs lhs, Rhs rhs) {
    swap(lhs, rhs);
    swap(rhs, lhs);
};
```

Now, very importantly we should immediately notice that this concept supports reference variables right out of the box:

```
int&& a_rref = 0;
int&& b_rref = 0;
// valid...
using std::swap;
swap(a_rref, b_rref);
// ...which is reflected here
static_assert( FirstKindOfSwappable<int&&> );
```

<sup>(Now technically the Standard was talking in terms of objects which references aren't. Since references not only refer to objects <sup>or functions</sup> but are meant to transparently stand for them, we’ve actually provided a very desirable feature. Practically speaking we are now working in terms of *variables*, not just objects.)</sup>

There’s a very important connection here: `int&&` is the declared type of our variables, as well as the actual argument passed to the concept, which in turn ends up again as the declared type of our `lhs` and `rhs` requires parameters. Keep that in mind as we dig deeper.

[<kbd>Coliru</kbd> demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52f856f41e80349e)

## Expressions

Now what about that second bit that mentions lvalues and rvalues? Well, here we’re not dealing in variables any more but instead in terms of *expressions*. Can we write a concept for that? Well, there’s a certain expression-to-type encoding we can use. Namely the one used by `decltype` as well as `std::declval` in the other direction. This leads us to:

```
template<typenaome Lhs, typename Rhs = Lhs>
concept bool SecondKindOfSwappable = requires(Lhs lhs, Rhs rhs) {
    swap(std::forward<Lhs>(lhs), std::forward<Rhs>(rhs));
    swap(std::forward<Rhs>(rhs), std::forward<Lhs>(lhs));

    // another way to express the first requirement
    swap(std::declval<Lhs>(), std::declval<Rhs>());
};
```

Which is what you ran into! And as you found out, the concept must be used in a different way:

```
// not valid
//swap(0, 0);
//     ^- rvalue expression of type int
//        decltype( (0) ) => int&&
static_assert( !SecondKindOfSwappable<int&&> );
// same effect because the expression-decltype/std::declval encoding
// cannot properly tell apart prvalues and xvalues
static_assert( !SecondKindOfSwappable<int> );

int a = 0, b = 0;
swap(a, b);
//   ^- lvalue expression of type int
//      decltype( (a) ) => int&
static_assert( SecondKindOfSwappable<int&> );
```

If you find that non-obvious, take a look at the connection at play this time: we have an lvalue expression of type `int`, which becomes encoded as the `int&` argument to the concept, which gets restored to an expression in our constraint by `std::declval<int&>()`. Or in a more roundabout way, by `std::forward<int&>(lhs)`.

[<kbd>Coliru</kbd> demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40ca85ebafc41652)

## Putting it together

What appears on the cppreference entry is a summary of the `Swappable` concept specified by the Ranges TS. If I were to guess, I would say that the Ranges TS settled on giving the `Swappable` parameters to stand for expressions for the following reasons:

- we can write `SecondKindOfSwappable` in terms of `FirstKindOfSwappable` as given by the following <sup>nearly</sup>:

  ```
  template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs = Lhs>
  concept bool FirstKindOfSwappable = SecondKindOfSwappable<Lhs&, Rhs&>;
  ```

  This recipe can be applied in many but not all cases, making it sometimes possible to express a concept parametrised on types-of-variables in terms of the same concept parametrised on expressions-hidden-in-types. But it’s usually not possible to go the other way around.
- constraining on `swap(std::forward<Lhs>(lhs), std::forward<Rhs>(rhs))` is expected to be an important enough scenario; off the top of my head it comes up in business such as:

  ```
  template<typename Val, typename It>
  void client_code(Val val, It it)
      requires Swappable<Val&, decltype(*it)>
  //                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^--.
  //                                          |
  //  hiding an expression into a type! ------`
  {
      ranges::swap(val, *it);
  }
  ```
- consistency: for the most part, other concepts of the TS follow the same convention and are parametrised over types of expressions

But why for the most part?

Because there is a third kind of concept parameter: the type that stand for… a type. A good example of that is `DerivedFrom<Derived, Base>()` which value does not give you valid expressions (or ways to use variables) in the usual sense.

In fact, in e.g. `Constructible<Arg, Inits...>()` the first argument `Arg` can arguably be interpreted in two ways:

- `Arg` stands for a type, i.e. taking constructibility as an inherent property of a type
- `Arg` is the declared type of a variable being constructed, i.e. the constraint implies that `Arg imaginary_var { std::declval<Inits>()... };` is valid

## How should I write my own concepts?

I’ll conclude with a personal note: I think the reader should not conclude (yet) that they should write their own concepts the same way just because concepts over expressions appear, at least from the perspective of a concept writer, to be a superset of concepts over variables.

There are other factors at play, and my concern is namely with usability from the perspective of a concept client <sup>and all these details I only mentioned in passing, too</sup>. But that doesn’t really have to do with the question and this answer is already long enough, so I’ll leave that story for another time.

Comment: This all makes sense, but it's still annoying that `void f(Swappable&);` and `template <Swappable S> f(S&);` don't do what I mean.  I suppose I can always just write my own `template <typename S, typename T=S> concept bool LvalSwappable = Swappable<S&,T&>;`.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>I'm still very new to concepts, so feel free to point out any errors I need to fix in this answer.  The answer is divided into three sections: The first directly regards the use of `std::forward`, the second expands on `Swappable`, and the third regards the internal error.</sup>

This appears to be a typo<sup>1</sup>, and likely should be `requires(T&& t, U&& u)`.  In this case, perfect forwarding is used to ensure that the concept will be properly evaluated for both lvalue and rvalue references, guaranteeing that only lvalue references will be marked as swappable.

The full [Ranges TS `Swappable` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/concepts/Swappable), which this is based on, is fully defined as:

```
template <class T>
concept bool Swappable() {
    return requires(T&& a, T&& b) {
               ranges::swap(std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<T>(b));
           };
}

template <class T, class U>
concept bool Swappable() {
    return ranges::Swappable<T>() &&
           ranges::Swappable<U>() &&
           ranges::CommonReference<const T&, const U&>() &&
           requires(T&& t, U&& u) {
               ranges::swap(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u));
               ranges::swap(std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<T>(t));
           };
}
```

The concept shown on the [Constraints and concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) page is a simplified version of this, which appears to be intended as a minimal implementation of library concept `Swappable`.  As the full definition specifies `requires(T&&, U&&)`, it stands to reason that this simplified version should as well.  `std::forward` is thus used with the expectation that `t` and `u` are forwarding references.

<sup>1: [Cubbi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356761/why-use-stdforward-in-concepts#comment75754691_44356761), made while I was testing code, doing research, and eating supper, confirms that it's a typo.</sup>

---

[The following expands on `Swappable`.  Feel free to skip it if this doesn't concern you.]

<sup>Note that this section only applies if `Swappable` is defined outside namespace `std`; if defined in `std`, as it appears to be in [the draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4382.pdf), the two `std::swap()`s will automatically be considered during overload resolution, meaning no additional work is required to include them.  Thanks go to Cubbi for linking to the draft and stating that `Swappable` was taken directly from it.</sup>

Note, however, that the simplified form by itself isn't a full implementation of `Swappable`, unless `using std::swap` has already been specified.  [`[swappable.requirements/3]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/utility.requirements#swappable.requirements-3) states that overload resolution must consider both the two `std::swap()` templates and any `swap()`s found by ADL (i.e., resolution must proceed as if the using-declaration `using std::swap` had been specified).  As concepts cannot contain using-declarations, a more complete `Swappable` might look something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U = T>
concept bool ADLSwappable = requires(T&& t, U&& u) {
    swap(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u));
    swap(std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<T>(t));
};

template<typename T, typename U = T>
concept bool StdSwappable = requires(T&& t, U&& u) {
    std::swap(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u));
    std::swap(std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<T>(t));
};

template<typename T, typename U = T>
concept bool Swappable = ADLSwappable<T, U> || StdSwappable<T, U>;
```

This expanded `Swappable` will allow for proper detection of parameters that fulfil the library concept, [like so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53b40dfc934bf157).

---

[The following regards GCC's internal error, and isn't directly related to `Swappable` itself.  Feel free to skip it if this doesn't concern you.]

To use this, however, `f()` needs a few modifications.  Rather than:

```
void f(Swappable& x) {}
```

One of the following should instead be used:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& x) requires Swappable<T&&> {}

template<typename T>
void f(T& x) requires Swappable<T&> {}
```

This is due to an interaction between GCC and concept resolution rules, and will probably be sorted out in future versions of the compiler.  Using a constraint-expression sidesteps the interaction that I believe is responsible for the internal error, making it a viable (if more verbose) stopgap measure for the time being.

The internal error appears to be caused by the way GCC handles concept resolution rules.  When it encounters this function:

```
void f(Swappable& x) {}
```

As function concepts can be overloaded, concept resolution is performed when concept names are encountered in certain contexts (such as when used as a constrained type specifier, like `Swappable` is here).  Thus, GCC attempts to resolve `Swappable` as specified by concept resolution rule #1, [in the **Concept resolution** section of this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

1. As `Swappable` is used without a parameter list, it takes a single wildcard as its argument.  This wildcard can match any possible template parameter (whether type, non-type, or template), and thus is a perfect match for `T`.
2. As `Swappable`'s second parameter doesn't correspond to an argument, its default template argument will be used, as specified after the numbered rules; I believe this to be the problem.  As `T` is currently `(wildcard)`, a simplistic approach would be to temporarily instantiate `U` as either another wildcard or a copy of the first wildcard, and determine whether `Swappable<(wildcard), (wildcard)>` matches the pattern `template<typename T, typename U>` (it does); it could then deduce `T`, and use that to properly determine whether it resolves to the `Swappable` concept.

   Instead, GCC appears to have reached a Catch-22: It can't instantiate `U` until it deduces `T`, but it can't deduce `T` until it determines whether this `Swappable` correctly resolves to the `Swappable` concept... which it can't do without `U`.  So, it needs to figure out what `U` is before it can figure out whether we have the right `Swappable`, but it needs to know whether we have the right `Swappable` before it can figure out what `U` is; faced with this unresolvable conundrum, it has an aneurysm, keels over, and dies.

Comment: Are `t` and `u` really forwarding references?  `T` and `U` aren't template parameters of a function template...

Comment: I took that Swappable concept for cppreference as-is from an earlier draft of Ranges TS. I don't remember which Ranges version was current at the time, but [n4382](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4382.pdf) is an example of where it appears this way (in [concepts.lib.corelang.swappable] ).

Comment: Replacing `T t` with `T&& t` in the concept definition doesn't seem to have changed much.  `t` is still an lvalue of type `std::remove_reference_t<T>`.  `decltype(t)` could be different, but isn't used.  So the basic point is `Swappable` is meant to be used with a reference, not a scalar type?  This is very unintuitive.  In plain English, we say `int` and `std::string` are "swappable", not references to `int` and to `std::string`.

Comment: Also, if I have it right, these semantics make it harder to use the short template function forms.  I think `void f(Swappable&&);` should work and usually take just lvalues, but it looks weird.

Comment: @aschepler They appear to be forwarding references, at the very least; I'm not sure if this is actually specified by the Concepts TS, though, or just part of GCC's implementation.  According to the CPPRefeference page, a `requires-expression`'s `parameter-list` is "a comma-separated list of parameters like in a function declaration"; this suggests that they use function template deduction rules, which would allow forwarding references.  The use of `std::forward` also suggests that `requires` uses forwarding references, [as does testing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/499cdb1d4b1a6d08).

Comment: @Cubbi Ah, that's where it's from.  Looking at that draft, `[concepts.lib.corelang.swappable/3]` requires that the overload set considered by `Swappable`'s `requires` clause must include the two `swap()`s in `<utility>` and all `swap()`s found by ADL.  This means that the concept itself, as shown there, would require `using std::swap` to have been previously specified.  I suspect that the concept would officially be defined in namespace `std`, and thus automatically include the two `std::swap()`s; if defined in the global namespace, however, additional work is required to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I'll note that my extended version is only intended for use if the concept is defined outside the standard namespace.

Comment: Took a closer look while updating the answer, and all signs definitely point to the concepts in the draft being defined in `std`.  `std::is_copy_assignable` is used unqualified (in concept `CopyAssignable`, defined directly above `Swappable`), `std::is_move_assignable` is used unqualified (in `MoveAssignable`, above `CopyAssignable`), other members of `std` are used unqualified throughout, `std::placeholders` is used as `using namespace placeholders` (in `[alg.lex.comparison]`), and the Scope section indicates that it's an extension to the standard library.  Again, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @aschepler I'm not actually sure why it appears to exclude scalars, in all honesty.  My best guess is that the logic is since passing by value prevents the original from being modified, the originals aren't swappable in contexts where they're passed by value.  Other than that, it might just be a side effect of the concept being defined in terms of `swap()`.

Comment: `void f(Swappable&);` should work if lvalues of the passed type can be swapped, while excluding rvalues without checking whether rvalues of the type can be swapped.  `void f(Swappable&&);` would be a more general form, that depends solely on the concept to exclude undesirable parameters; it should allow both for types whose lvalues can be swapped and ones whose rvalues can be swapped, and choose lvalues whenever not explicitly passed an rvalue.

Comment: [It seems there are some issues with that at the moment](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89f65b7c8e8a765d), although I'm not sure if the problem here is on GCC's end, if it has to do with the way constrained type specifiers are expanded, or if it's caused by the way `Swappable` is implemented here.  (Problems are listed in `main()`, with the lines that exhibit them commented out.)

Comment: Your example is exactly what I expect, and probably not a g++ bug.  The template parameters are deduced in the normal way from the function template, and only then plugged into the concept.  E.g. in `s2(i)`, template argument deduction proceeds as though `SelfSwappable` were a type template parameter, resulting in the type `int`, then this is checked against the concept, which fails.  In other words, `void s2(SelfSwappable&);` should be equivalent to `template <typename S> void s2(S&) requires SelfSwappable<S>;`.

Comment: ... This is why I say arguments of a `requires` cannot be forwarding references, just like in `template <typename T> struct X { void f(T&& arg); };`, `arg` is not a forwarding reference.