# write a concept check library, but fail on all fundemental arithmetic types

Tags: c++, concept, c++17

Things went wrong when I was testing whether fundemental arithmetic types like int, and raw pointers like int*, can be pre-incrementabl/post-incrementable.

```
//has_operator_overload_functions.hpp
namespace concept_check {
template <class T>
T create_T();

struct disambiguation_t2 {};
struct disambiguation_t1 {
    constexpr operator disambiguation_t2 () const noexcept;
};
}

# define create_has_op_overload_fn_test(fn_name, ret_t_of_op_to_test) \
template <class T>                                          \
auto has_ ## fn_name (disambiguation_t1) -> ret_t_of_op_to_test;     \
template <class T>                                          \
void has_ ## fn_name (disambiguation_t2);                    \
template <class T>                                          \
inline constexpr const bool has_ ## fn_name ## _v = !is_same_v<decltype(has_ ## fn_name <T>(disambiguation_t1{})), void>;

# define create_check_op_overload_fn_return_type_test(fn_name, ret_t_of_op_to_test, result_t) \
create_has_op_overload_fn_test(fn_name, ret_t_of_op_to_test) \                              
_create_check_op_overload_fn_return_type_test(fn_name, ret_t_of_op_to_test, result_t)

# define _create_check_op_overload_fn_return_type_test(fn_name, ret_t_of_op_to_test, result_t) \
template <class T>          \                                                         
constexpr const bool is_ ## fn_name () noexcept {      \                           

    if constexpr(has_ ## fn_name ## _v<T>)                  \                                 
        return is_convertible_v< ret_t_of_op_to_test , result_t >; \
    else             \                                
        return 0;                                \
}                                                  \
template <class T>                                      \
inline constexpr const bool is_ ## fn_name ## _v = is_ ## fn_name <T>();

namespace concept_check {
create_check_op_overload_fn_return_type_test(pre_incrementable, 
decltype(++create_T<T>()), T&)
create_check_op_overload_fn_return_type_test(post_incrementable, 
decltype(create_T<T>()++), T)
}//namespace concept_check
```

```
//test.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include "has_operator_overload_functions.hpp"
using namespace concept_check;
struct A {
    A& operator ++ ();
    A operator ++ (int);
};
struct B {
    B& operator ++ ();
};
struct C {
    C operator ++ (int);
};
struct E {};
int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha

              << "incrementable\n\n"

              << "int\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<int> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<int> << std::endl

              << "\nchar\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<char> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<char> << std::endl

              << "\nfloat\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<float> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<float> << std::endl

              << "\ndouble\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<double> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<double> << std::endl

              << "\nchar*\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<char*> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<char*> << std::endl

              << "\nvoid*\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<void*> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<void*> << std::endl

              << "\nA\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<A> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<A> << std::endl

              << "\nB\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<B> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<B> << std::endl

              << "\nC\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<C> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<C> << std::endl

              << "\nE\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<E> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<E> << std::endl

              << "\nbool\n"
              << is_pre_incrementable_v<bool> << std::endl
              << is_post_incrementable_v<bool> << std::endl
}
```

I compiled it using

```
clang version 5.0.1-svn324012-1~exp1 (branches/release_50)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

, with command line args -std=c++17 -I .. and ran the binary file I got, and it gave out the following output:

```
incrementable

int
false
false

char
false
false

float
false
false

double
false
false

char*
false
false

void*
false
false

A
true
true

B
true
false

C
false
true

E
false
false

bool
false
false
```

As you can see, all the fundemental arithmetic types and raw pointers didn't pass the pre-icrementable/post-incrementable test.

Can any explain why this happened and how to fix this?

Comment: Self included question please. If the link rot we can't understand anything. If the code is too large, reduce it to a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: `create_T` is not declared. And don't use identifiers that begin with two underscores: these are reserved, meaning some compiler or compiler-provided library might `#define` them or give them special built-in meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create_check_op_overload_fn_return_type_test(pre_incrementable, decltype(++create_T<T>()), T&)
```

You are using `decltype(++create_T<T>())` as an effective constraint on your `is_pre_incrementable_v` check. For a type such as `A`, this is equivalent to testing e.g. `++A {}` which is valid, as reflected in your results.

For a type such as `int` however this is equivalent to testing `++0`, which is not a valid expression. (And so on for the other non-class types.)

There isn't an obvious fix. You could decide to constrain on e.g. `++create_T<T&>()` instead (it’s also a good time to mention [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)). But pay attention that this has the following consequence:

```
template<typename Arg>
auto under_constrained(Arg const& arg)
-> std::enable_if_t<is_pre_incrementable_v<Arg>>
{
    ++arg;
}

template<typename Arg>
auto over_constrained(Arg& arg)
-> std::enable_if_t<is_pre_incrementable_v<Arg>, std::decay_t<Arg>>
{
    auto copy = arg;
    ++copy;
    return copy;
}
```

- the first example is under-constrained because it effectively tests for `++mutable_arg` given an imaginary `Arg mutable_arg;` variable, but the body operates on an immutable variable (which of course will not be incrementable in most circumstances)
- the second example is over-constrained because e.g. if called on `int const immutable_variable = 0;` as an argument it effectively tests for `++immutable_arg`, but the body operates on an `int` variable

Now, these example could be tweaked so that they are instead constrained on e.g. `is_pre_incrementable_v<Arg const&>` and `is_pre_incrementable_v<std::decay_t<Arg>&>` respectively. But that requires care on the concept user’s part. That’s why the fix is not necessarily the go-to solution.

It all comes down to [the meaning of template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44411583/726300) for a given concept.

Comment: So you means that, if  ++create_T<T>() is equivalent to ++T{}, but because for non-class, default-initialization equals zero-initialization, so it becomes ++0, which makes is_pre_incrementable returns 0.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu no, `create_T<T>()` does not involve any sort of initialization and is not equivalent to `T {}` (in my answer I was specifically talking about the concrete class `A`). you can’t perform `++0` just like you can’t perform `++3` or `++std::move(i)` (where `i` is an `int` variable) because of the rules of the language ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33403cb4d4208f06)) and that’s all that matters.

Comment: I see. But I still can't understand why ++int == ++0, can you explain that further?

Comment: @LucDantion And when I defined create_has_op_overload_fn_test(dereferenceable, decltype(*create_T<T>()))
, it works well for both non-class and class.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu remember that `create_T<int>` is the same kind of function as e.g. `int make_a_three() { return 3; }`, so the analogy is that `++make_a_three()` is as senseless as `++3`. the difference you’re looking for between e.g. unary `*` and prefix increment is that only the latter (normally) modifies its argument, which makes it tricky to define on transient values (which is why the language decides not to bother)

Comment: It doesn't work because it's an xvalue;<p>It will work if ```int i = create_T<int>(), ++i ```, so that i will be a lvalue and copy ctor will not be considered because copy elision in C++ or if ```int &&i = create_T<int>(), ++i```.<p>Am I corret, @LucDantion ?

Comment: @JiaHaoXu the same effect can be achieved in a more concise fashion with `++create_T<int&>()`, which is why I mention it in the answer and go into more depth with the consequences of making such a choice

Comment: I tried to use std::declval<int>, but it still failed, only std::declval<int&> succeeded. It seems that there's no builtin operator overload for right value reference of builtin types.